# Is there any way to add two url in config file and call from page object file using protractor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, gulp-protractor

I am able to call baseUrl from one page object file but i am not able to call schoolUrl from another page object file. I am trying to call url from config file without adding whole url in page object file.

My config.js file is

```
exports.config = {
   allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        args: ["--start-maximized", "--window-size=1630,963"]
    }
  },
  directConnect: true,
  port: null,
  baseUrl: 'https://class.com',
  schoolUrl: 'https://school.com'
 }
```

my page object file to call baseUrl

```
   import {browser, by, element, ElementFinder, ExpectedConditions, promise} from 'protractor';

export class SchoolPage {
    public staffUrl = '';

    public async navigateTo(): Promise<any> {
    return browser.get(``)  ; 
    }
```

How can i call schoolUrl from config.js file like base url is called directly without adding url in po file

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your config

```
exports.config = {
   allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        args: ["--start-maximized", "--window-size=1630,963"]
    }
  },
  directConnect: true,
  port: null,
  baseUrl: 'https://class.com',
  params: {
    schoolUrl: 'https://school.com'
  },
}
```

then you can refer to that variable in your code like this `browser.params.schoolUrl`